# Akamai has issue with ASPX post backs

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, akamai

I'm using Akamai Edge Server to serve up all my web content except for html and aspx pages. The issue I am having is with a language switcher that does a post back to the same page and then based on the language does a `response.redirect` to the same page in the other language folder.

The steps that happen are:

1. go to page /en/default.aspx
2. select a different language such as fr.
3. The aspx code on that page calls a header user control which will then redirect to the proper language page
4. It fails on the postback to the control and I get an access denied on  /en/default.aspx which is an akamai page not on my webserver.

If I access my dotnet server directly you'll see that the page will do a postback to itself /en/default.aspx then a `response.redirect` to /fr/default.aspx

Comment: Do you actually _have_ any ASPX content in other languages? You might want to use standard .NET mechanisms for localization rather than depending on this redirect trick.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I figured it out that akamai edge server doesn't allow posts by default and you have to enable it.  Im new to using akamai in this way didn't think it would deny such a common thing.